# Palindrome function proof one-to-one, onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics, palindrome

This is the question:

Let $X=\text{{a,b}}$. A palindrome over $X$ is a string $\alpha$ for which $\alpha = \alpha^R$ (the string that reads the same forward and backward). An example of a palindrome over $X$ is $bbaabb$. Define a function from $X^*$ to the set of palindromes over $X$ as $f(\alpha)= \alpha \alpha^R$. Is $f$ one-to-one? Is $f$ onto? Prove your answers.

For the first part I have:

Let $\beta,\gamma \in X^*$. A function $f:X^* \to X$ is one-to-one if it satisfies the condition:

$$\forall  \beta, \gamma \in X(f(\beta)=f(\gamma) \Rightarrow \beta = \gamma) $$
Here: $$f(\beta)=\beta\beta^R, f(\gamma)=\gamma\gamma^R$$
then $$\beta\beta^R = \gamma\gamma^R \Rightarrow \beta = \gamma$$
is this sufficient to prove that it is one-to-one?

As for the proving whether or not it is onto I have no idea how to start.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\alpha^2$, if that means concatenation, $\alpha=\alpha^2$ is never possible as they are strings of different length.

Comment: oh! made a typo should be $\alpha ^R$

Comment: What is $X^*$? You define a function from $X^*$ to the set of all palindromes over $X$, but write $f : X^* \to X$. This means that the codomain of $f$ is $X = \{a, b\}$, which is not the same thing as the set of palindromes.

Comment: @manthanomen $X^*$ is a function with elements $\beta , \gamma$. Although, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @Nolohice $f$ is your function, $X^*$ is the domain of $f$. If $X^*$ is the set of all palindromes over $X$, and you're talking about a function which takes palindromes to palindromes, then you should write $f : X^* \to X^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\alpha\alpha^R $ is always a string of even length, and so palindromes of odd length cannot be in the image of $f$. So for strings of even length to be palindrome things should repeat in the reversed way after the mid-point. Now you can see injectivity of $f$.

Comment: So then, can I provide an example in the codomain such as $\beta \gamma \beta$ which will not be in the range since $\alpha \alpha^R$ is always a string of even length?